# How to create temporary attribute & use that in json reponse in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, model-associations

I am new to ROR.
I am having a controller where i am getting the search results in available_users variable..

```
availble_users  //some active record result with id,name & address
available_users.each do |userstatus|
          userstatus.class_eval do
          attr_accessor :is_friend
          end
          if current_user.invitations.find_by(:friend_id => userstatus.id) //invitation is another table 
            userstatus.is_friend = "true"
          else
            userstatus.is_friend = "false"
          end
        end
         render json: available_users
```

but when i am getting the response on ajax request it is serving the same array without including is_friend column.

here is my json response.

```
id: 2
name: abc
address:
```

please can anyone figure me out why it is not appending this temporary attribute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you have will work if you pass the methods option to_json

```
    render json: available_users.to_json(:methods => :is_friend)
```

Or you could do this

```
    available_users.each do |userstatus|
      if current_user.invitations.find_by(:friend_id => userstatus.id) //invitation is another table 
        userstatus["is_friend"] = "true"
      else
        userstatus["is_friend"] = "false"
      end

    end
    render json: available_users
```

`[]=` is an alias for `write_attribute`

Comment: 2nd method doesn't working,i tried it.
showing "can't write unknown attribute `is_friend'"

for the 1st method is_friend not is in my invitation model,so how can i access it.
i created it temporary.

Comment: `attr_accessor` creates a getter and setter for `is_friend`. the getter is what it would call you pass it in the method option